# Accessing database outside of localhost with PHP and Wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost, wampserver

I am trying to access a database that is not in my localhost or in my network. I am WampServer so I can open the PHP file. I am trying this code bellow, just to see the connection working. but never works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang= "en" ><head></head><body>
<?php
        $DBConnect = @mysql_connect("xx.xx.xx.173:22289", "sa", "123456")
            Or die("<p>The database server is not available.</p>"."<p>Error Code" .mysql_connect_erno(). ":". mysql_connect_error());
        echo "<p>Successfully connected to the database server.</p>";

        $DBName = "Database01";
        @mysql_select_db($DBName)
            Or die("<p>The database is not available.</p>" . "<p>Error Code" . mysql_erno($DBConnect). ":" . mysql_error($DBConnect));
        echo "<p>Successfully opened the database.</p>";
mysql_close($DBConnect);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This port number they specified for me to use to access their database. I can connect in their virtual machinne trought this ip address, and inside the virtual machine I can access the database using the same ip adress and the the port im using in the code. login and password are, because I can log in in to the database using Microsoft SQL Server.

I tried to change the IP to xx.xx.xx.173,22289 and also did not work.
The webpage takes like 7min to load and when it loads, show just the HTML part.

How I can access the database outside through the php file?

If is not possible to access a database especifing an IP adress with WampServer, how should I test the php files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you want change is the mysql* functions, they are depreciated.
http://www.php.net/mysql_select_db

You want to use PDO for your database connections in PHP:
http://php.net/pdo

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;', 'user', 'pass');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO DoesNotExist (x) VALUES (?)');
}
catch(Exception $e) {
     echo 'Exception -> ';
     var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

Example error:
     Exception -> string(91) "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.doesnotexist' doesn't exist"

Comment: Thanks, I gonna change it, do you know if is possible to access a database outside of the localhost using the wampserver?

Comment: I don't see why not. Just replace localhost with the IP or DNS of the database as you did. You will need to add error handling to catch the reason why you are unable to connect.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to connect to your server, follow this:**

- before login to whm
- click SQL Services
- click Additional MySQL Access Hosts
- add your ip
- click to save
- click again Additional MySQL Access Hosts
- and click to configure from all users (...configure access from all
  users' accounts, Click Here)

  $mysql_link = mysql_connect('your_host', 'your_u_name', 'your_pass') or die ('Server bağlantı hatası!');

No need to write the port number. good luck..

Comment: I am not using whm, do you know how it should be for wamp server?

Comment: I am not using wamp server. but I thing no need to write port number. if you want try it : mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die('Error '.mysql_error()); and write error here. I'm using it [link](http://www.appservnetwork.com) and had no problems.

Comment: This is the error:
Warning: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away'

; I am using the port because the server specified this port to connect in the DB. I tried to connect through Toad for SQL and worked the connection, so I guess im not specifying the port in my Wamp Server; I gonna try this link you sent, thanks!